# shell command with unexpected quotes

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am running a script it has:

```
...
echo 3:${WRITE_TIME}
WRITE_TIME_QUOTES=\"${WRITE_TIME}\"
echo 4:${WRITE_TIME_QUOTES}
${ADDR_BEELINE}/beeline ... --hivevar write_time=${WRITE_TIME_QUOTES} ;hive_status=$?
```

I pass the date time with spaces as argument to this script and both the 2 variables: `WRITE_TIME` and `WRITE_TIME_QUOTES` are displayed as expected:

```
3:2021-11-24 17:00:00
4:"2021-11-24 17:00:00"
```

The command is expected to be:

```
/home/data/hive/bin/beeline ... --hivevar write_time="2021-11-24 17:00:00"
```

However, the command actually executed comprises extra quotes which are not written in the script:

```
/home/data/hive/bin/beeline ... --hivevar 'write_time="2021-11-24' '17:00:00"'
```

I did not put them at all, why did they appear and how to get rid of them? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you just want `beeline ... write_time="${WRITE_TIME}"`

Comment: hi @muru  Thanks for your reply. I retried `beeline ... --hivevar write_time="${WRITE_TIME_QUOTES}" ` but the commands becomes `--hivevar 'write_time="2021-11-24 17:00:00"'`

Comment: Are you using `set -xv` to check the command? It adds quotes for clarity, they aren't in fact sent to the command.

Comment: @user2894829 double check my comment, I used `WRITE_TIME`

Comment: @muru my bad! It works! The commnd is displayed as `--hivevar 'write_time=2021-11-24 17:00:00'`. This looks incorrect but the argument `2021-11-24 17:00:00` is correctly parsed.. why..

Comment: Seems like the same issue as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658837/preserving-double-quotes-in-a-command-created-from-variables-in-shell-script/658839#658839